# dynamic string - execute as sql-query

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am writing a stored procedure by framing a dynamic string :

the following query is a string stored in a variable.
How will I execute this string ?

```
 DELETE FROM PopularTrends          
 WHERE PopularID NOT IN           
 (          
 SELECT  PopularID          
 FROM   (SELECT *,          
           Row_number()          
             OVER(          
               PARTITION BY COUNTRY,HRefTopic          
               ORDER BY LastModifiedTime desc) AS RN          
    FROM   populartrends )A          
    WHERE  RN = 1          
 )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(1000)
SET @query=N'DELETE FROM PopularTrends          
 WHERE PopularID NOT IN           
 (          
 SELECT  PopularID          
 FROM   (SELECT *,          
           Row_number()          
             OVER(          
               PARTITION BY COUNTRY,HRefTopic          
               ORDER BY LastModifiedTime desc) AS RN          
    FROM   populartrends )A          
    WHERE  RN = 1          
 )'
EXEC sp_executesql @query
```

Reference:

- [sp_executesql (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx)

Comment: Would you know what that would be in BigQuery?